# MatLab simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've never asked questions about matlab on this site, and I'm not into matlab, but I have to create model in simulink.
Can someone help me how to create simulink model that will describe this equation:

```
8y(k+2) - 5y(k+1) + y(k) = 2u(k)

y(o)= 0 ; y(1) = 0 ; u(k) = 1(k)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming that `k` is the time step, `u(k)` the input and `y(k)` the output at time step `k`,  your system would be accusal as you want to know `y(k+2)` at time step `k`.

So I assume you might mean `(k-2)` instead, which you can realize with a `1/z^2` block (`1/z` for `(k-1)`) of the input plus the gains you have for each y. Your output would be then

`y(k) = 2*u(k) - 8*y(k-2) + 5*y(k-1)`

and the `y(0)` and `y(1)` are the initial conditions for the `1/z` blocks

Comment: thanks for explanation, It should be 8y(k+1) , not (k+2).  I didn't mean (k-2)